# Return elements between two variable indexes in a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I want to return elements between two variable indexes in a list.

For example, given this list -

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

I want to loop through the list using to variables for index values. Let’s call the index values X and Y.
So if X equals an index value of 0 and Y equals a value of 5, I need to loop through the index 0-5 and return all of the element values. X and Y could later become index values of 5 through 8 for example.
How would I accomplish this?

Comment: by a given list indexes or list values?

Comment: What exactly is the problem or question? As it stands, it seems like you could simply write what you have described in C#.

Comment: Sorry  O. R. Mapper, I would have put in code but I'm still learning and didn't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [List.GetRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx)

```
var result = list.GetRange(X, Y-X+1);
```

or a simple for loop

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
for (int i = X; i <= Y; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```

or reinventing the wheel the way you want

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetRange<T>(this IList<T> list, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)
        {
            yield return list[i];
        }
    }
}

foreach(var item in list.GetRange(0, 5))
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks dotctor!!!!! , List.GetRange was what I needed. I created a new list List<int> newlist = list.GetRange(X, Y - X + 1);   and now I can loop through that list to get the element values which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @KevinMoore Since this was apparently your chosen answer, please mark it by answer by using the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @Mackan , Ha, new to stack exchange..done. I liked all the other answers too but the GetRange is perfect. This form is fantastic! all Thanks to all the fast, great replies.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Enumerable.Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Enumerable.Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var res = list.Skip(noOfElementToSkip).Take(noOfElementsToTake);
```

To using variable as indexes

```
var res = list.Skip(x).Take(y-x+1);
```

**Note** You need to pass the start element index to Skip and for taking number of elements you need to pass number of element you want in Take parameter minus the start element number, plus one list is zero-based index.

Comment: I mean I was going to refine my answer to give what OP exactly wants and  that is what you suggested.

Comment: I think it should be `Take(y-x+1)`

Comment: _So if X equals an index value of 0 and Y equals a value of 5, I need to loop through the index 0-5 and return all of the element values_ @Mackan

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = 0, y = 5;
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
for (; x < y; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[x]);
}
```

This would work if X is always smaller than Y.
If you don't know which is bigger add this before the loop:

```
 if (x > y) 
 {
      x = x ^ y;
      y = y ^ x;
      x = x ^ y;
  }
```

Comment: how about using `Interlocked.Exchange`?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
int X = 0, Y = 5;
Enumerable.Range(X, Y - X + 1)
.Select(index => list[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should do the trick -

```
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        int startindex = 1;
        int endIndex = 7;
        var subList = list.Skip(startindex).Take(endIndex - startindex-1).ToList();
```